# "builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'reshape'" what does this mean?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a novice, so this question may be somewhat obvious for someone.

```
import numpy as np
print("array")
array = np.arange(8)
matrix = np.array.reshape(2,4)
print(matrix)
```

The result is this.

```
array
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-88e5e9409344> in <module>
      2 print("array")
      3 array = np.arange(8)
----> 4 matrix = np.array.reshape(2,4)
      5 print(matrix)

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `reshape` on `np.array`, which is a function that is used to create a new array. You created your variable `array`. Try to use this variable instead of `np.array`: `matrix = array.reshape(2,4)`

Comment: @UeliDeSchwert Thank you! It does work! Is it unnecessary to put 'np' in front of 'array'? Why?

Comment: The `np.` identifies functions in the `numpy` module.  There is a `np.array` function.  And to reduce your confusion change variable names.  For example `arr = np.arange(3)` or `x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)`.  Avoid names that look too much like existing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're calling reshape on `np.array`, which is a function that is used to create a new array.

You already created your variable `array`.
Try to use this variable instead of `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np
print("array")
array = np.arange(8)
matrix = array.reshape(2,4) # <-- remove the "np." to access a function on your array
print(matrix)
```

Why is this?

`myArray = np.array(k)` is a function that creates a new NumPy array using the input `k`.
The result of this function is returned and saved to a variable (in my case `myArray`).

On this array, you can call functions to manipulate it (like `reshape`).

What you tried to do: You used `np.array` (remember, the function that creates an array). You did not use your array, but used a function pointer instead.

Comment: so you mean that because I already made an array, I don't need to put 'np' to make a matrix?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Maybe this makes it more clear.